# I am having a hard time understanding this question.

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, notation, graphing-functions, interval-arithmetic

Use the graph of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ to answer the following.

a. $(1)$
b. $(−7)$
c. $(7) − (4)$
d. $((−5))$
e. Find the $x$-value(s) that satisfy $() = 6.$
f. State the domain of $f(x)$ in interval notation.
g. State the range of $g(x)$ in interval notation.

[Tne graph of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrCdM.jpg)

Comment: You simply need to understand what , say, g(1) means. If $g$ is a function, when function $g$ takes as input the number 1, what the function sends back as output is called $g(1)$ ( read : "g of 1" or " image of 1 under function $g$"). This information is recorded on the graph by the fact that the point $(1, g(1))$ belongs to the curve representing $g$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the graph, we have: $$g(1)=4 \land f(-7)=-4 \land f(7)-g(4)=1 \land f(g(-5))=f(4)=6$$
Also, we have $$f(x)=6 \leftrightarrow x=4\lor x=9$$
And range of $g(x)$ is $2\leq y\leq 7$.

Comment: What is the domain ? Thank you

Comment: The domain of $f(x)$ is $-10\leq x \leq 9$.

Comment: is this interval notation ? Thank you so much this is all confusing

Comment: @Mommydom: yes, it is.